# Creating a Macbook Pro Touchbar .dylib extension

Tags: dylib, macbookpro-touch-bar

I'm developing a game for Mac using GameMaker Studio 2, which allows you to add extensions created with another programs. When using Mac OS X, GameMaker needs an extension of type `.dylib`, which includes the functions you call in GameMaker when you add the extension to your project.

I would like to add some TouchBar functions in my video games, and I already know how to develop apps with Touchbar using Xcode, but the problem is that I have no idea of what I have to do to create a `.dylib` library so as to use Touchbar functions through GameMaker (I don't even know if something like that is possible). Is there someone who knows how to do this?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stackoverflow! I recommend you check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) to improve the chances of getting useful answers, and also how to create [Complete, Minimal, and Verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).